# RestKit not mapping Images from JSON

Tags: ios, json, restkit

I'm **not able to map the Images from my JSON** response correctly, and I can't figure out why.

Here is error: **"W restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMappingOperation.m:244 Failed transformation of value at keyPath 'images'. No strategy for transforming from '__NSArrayM' to 'Images'"**

Here is JSON:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2013-05-10T03:09:39Z",
    "feed": [{
        "headline": "Head text",
        "links": {
            "api": {
                "news": {
                    "href": "http://api.website.com/v1/91"
                },
                "self": {
                    "href": "http://api.website.com/v1/91"
                }
            },
            "web": {
                "href": "http://website.com/the/story"
            },
            "mobile": {
                "href": "http://m.website.com/wireless/story?storyId=9254113"
            }
        },
        "source": "Associated Press",
        "description": "Description text.",
        "images": [{
            "height": 324,
            "alt": "",
            "width": 576,
            "name": "Name text",
            "caption": "Caption text.",
            "url": "http://a.website.com/media/2013/0508.jpg"
        }],
```

Feed.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) Links *links;
@property (nonatomic, strong) Images *images;
@property (nonatomic, strong) Video *video;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *headline;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *source;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *published;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *description;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *premium;

+ (RKObjectMapping *) mapping;
```

Feed.m

```
+ (RKObjectMapping *)mapping {
    RKObjectMapping *objectMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[self class] usingBlock:^(RKObjectMapping *mapping) {
        [mapping mapKeyPathsToAttributes:
         @"headline", @"headline",
         @"source", @"source",
         @"published", @"published",
         @"description", @"description",
         @"premium", @"premium",
         nil];
        [mapping hasOne:@"links" withMapping:[Links mapping]];
        [mapping hasOne:@"images" withMapping:[Images mapping]];
        //[mapping hasMany:@"images" withMapping:[Images mapping]];
        [mapping hasOne:@"video" withMapping:[Video mapping]];
    }];

    return objectMapping;
}
```

Images.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *height;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *width;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *caption;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURL *url;

+ (RKObjectMapping *) mapping;
```

Images.m

```
+ (RKObjectMapping *)mapping {
    RKObjectMapping *objectMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[self class] usingBlock:^(RKObjectMapping *mapping) {
        [mapping mapKeyPathsToAttributes:
         @"height", @"height",
         @"width", @"width",
         @"caption", @"caption",
         @"url", @"url",
         nil];
    }];

    return objectMapping;
}
```

Everything else is mapping correctly except images.  I don't know if it has to do with it being an Array but it only having one result, so its not necessarily an array?  And if its not, then how I would write that...  I'm just not totally clear on why its not mapping.

As you can see I tried both `hasMany:` and `hasOne:` mapping and neither worked, I got the same error.

I tried using `NSLog(@"url image: %@", feedLocal.images.url);' but get`(null)`.  Even though I thought it would work because`NSLog(@"href web: %@", feedLocal.links.web.href);` works perfectly for my links href.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks so much!

Comment: Restkit Won't understand array - use transformable!

Comment: @BharatGulati Thanks for the response! I'm not sure what that means exactly, can you give me a snippet of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Feed.h you need to change your `images` property to be:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *images;
```

And you should set the mapping to `hasMany:`.

Comment: thanks for the response!  When I change the code per your suggestion, I get an error saying that `property url not found on object of type NSArray`, what other tweak should I make?

Comment: `[mapping hasMany:@"images" withMapping:[Images mapping]];` is what I changed mapping to

Comment: Strange... Try trace logging RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/ObjectMapping", RKLogLevelTrace);

Comment: Thats a neat tip.  What should I be looking for exactly here though?

Comment: If I knew what it was going to say I wouldn't be puzzled as to why the above change didn't work :-) Something to do with mapping 'images' or 'Images'. Just more information about what it was doing before it logs the error.

Comment: Ah, gotcha.  I just can't figure out the slight difference with how to map this one, its driving me nuts